# List picker not showing items.

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, viewmodel, listpicker

I have a list picker when clicking on the control to select another item it seems to look like it is going to work but is all white I can sometimes get it to select another item but cant see what is selected until you are off of it. This is how I have it set up.  When I set it to full mode the name space is the only thing that shows not the actual name of the item. All I am trying to do is upon loading the view I need to load the listPicker with values.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TankTypeName}" Style="{StaticResource  PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TankTypeName}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyLight}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <TextBox Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0" Name="TextBoxProjectName" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" />
    <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,28,0,0" Name="TextBlockProjectName" Text="Tank Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <toolkit:ListPicker Header="Tank Type:" ItemsSource="{Binding TankTypes}"
                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" 
                            FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding PickerFullModeItemTemplate}"
                            SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedTankTypes,Mode=TwoWay}"

                            Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            Margin="6,144,0,0" Name="ListPickerTankType" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" >
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
</Grid>
```

View Model

```
private List<TankType> _tankType;

private ObservableCollection<Object> _selectedTankType= new ObservableCollection<object>(); 

    /// <summary>
    /// Collection of Tank Type objects.
    /// </summary>
public List<TankType> TankTypes
{
    get 
    { 
        return _tankType; 
    }

    set 
    {
        if (value != _tankType) 
        {
            _tankType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TankType");
        }
    }
}


public ObservableCollection<object> SelectedTankTypes
{
    get 
    { 
        return _selectedTankType; 
    }

    set 
    {
        if (_selectedTankType == value) 
        {
            return;
        }

        _selectedTankType = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTankTypes");
    }
}
```

This is a edit page so in the constructor of the view.

```
public TaskDetail() 
{
     InitializeComponent();
     var tankTypeViewModel = new ViewModels.TankVewModel();
     tankTypeViewModel.GetTankTypes();
     ListPickerTankType.DataContext = tankTypeViewModel;
}
```

Revised OK I removed the height on the listpicker and now can see it made it bigger so the three items are there. I just cant seem to change the font color to black so I can see it when you click on the listpicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed to remove the height and set the foreground color to black.